# Section range in header : how to inherit section mark from previous page?

Tags: fancyhdr

Using fancyhdr and extramarks package, I would like to set a header whith the range of sections actually displayed on the page. Which means I have 3 possible cases:

- Only 1 section is displayed : only one number should appear in header.
- At least 2 sections are displayed : first and last number should appear in header.
- A previous section ends on top of the page, then a new section begins : number from last section, then last new number of the page should appear.

So far I manage to set up my code for the two fists cases with the ifthen package, but I can't figure out how to express the third case properly.

Here's a example :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead{}

\fancyhead[CE, CO]{\ifthenelse{\equal{\firstleftmark}{\lastleftmark}}
    {\firstleftmark}
    {\firstleftmark -- \lastleftmark}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \section{}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \section{}
    \lipsum[1-5]

    \section{}
    \lipsum[1-4]
    
\end{document}
```

Once compiled, the problem appears on page 2. Only the new section is taken into account. How to create a range number in the header "inheriting" the number of the ending section on top of the page?

Comment: As far as I can tell from the manual of `fancyhdr` the problem arises from the way `\rightmark` and `\leftmark` are defined: they refer to instances on *the same page* . Here you want to compare an instance on a previous page to an instance on a new page. Or better said: compare the stored value of `\lastleftmark` of the previous page to the new value of `\lastleftmark` on the new page. Provided I correctly understand the sentence *The `leftmark` contains the **L**eft argument of the **L**ast `\markboth` on the page.*  @cabohah answer seems to do that comparing.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know, how to do it using `fancyhdr` and `extramarks`, but here is a suggestion using [package `scrlayer-scrpage`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% shouldn't be needed any more
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[section]{section}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{%
  \Ifstr{\lefttopmark}{}% After deleting the marks or at the very beginning of
                        % the document, use \leftfirstmark instead of
                        % \lefttopmark
  {%
    \Ifstr{\leftfirstmark}{\rightbotmark}%
          {\leftfirstmark}%
          {\leftfirstmark\ -- \rightbotmark}%
  }%
  {%
    \Ifstr{\lefttopmark}{\rightbotmark}%
          {\lefttopmark}%
          {\lefttopmark\ -- \rightbotmark}%
  }%
}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection}{\thesection}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \section{}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \section{}
    \lipsum[1-5]

    \section{}
    \lipsum[1-4]
    
\end{document}
```

[image: three pages of output]

Comment: Thank you for your solution that gives the behavior I was hoping for. I am however not familiar at all with KOMA-script packages, so I guess I'll have some reading to do. Since this header behavior is only required for a part of my work, is it possible to use it as a pagestyle different from the main style in a master-file?

Comment: @Aktemon Yes. You can either change the pagestyle using `\chead` etc. inside the document wherever you want (and AFAIK it would even be local to groups), or you can define additional pairs of pagestyles (see section 18.2 of the KOMA-Script manual). The first approach should be easier, the second cleaner.